# element.scrollIntoView cuts off the top

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I am trying to scroll elements into view using the `.scrollIntoView()` function in JavaScript.

```
section.reference.value.scrollIntoView(
                            {
                                behavior: "smooth",
                                "block": "start",
                                "inline": "start"
                            }
                        );
```

It almost works perfectly, it scrolls everything necessary to show the element, except it always cuts it off by about 10px, and I don't think there is an option to give it an offset when scrolling.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

To use JavaScript [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to do smooth scroll with offset, you can call [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) with an object that has the top and behavior properties.

```
const element = document.getElementById("targetElement"); // Your target element
const headerOffset = 45;
const elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
const offsetPosition = elementPosition + window.pageYOffset - headerOffset;

window.scrollTo({
  top: offsetPosition,
  behavior: "smooth",
});
```

Comment: Are you saying to use scrollTo instead of scrollIntoView!

Comment: This solution does not work if the window is not the parent scrollable container.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by just creating a temporary element inside that element, and moving it using relative positioning to account for my own offset, then deleting it right after.